# Books on philosophical questions underpinning Halachah

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

In Deuteronomy, Moses says "For this command that I command you today is not a wonder to you and it is not distant..."   I want to explore the (possible) tension between this sentiment and laws whose logic may not be clear to us or where modern understanding changes the original rationale (e.g., using non-porous dishware going against practice of maintaining two sets). 
I'm sure this has been explored and would just appreciate the best source that lays out the arguments.  Thx.

Comment: Sorry, what non-porous dishware has to do with philosophy?

Comment: Why should the rules of kashrut involve maintaining two sets of silverware--why can't I just use a non-porous utensil once with milk and then wash it carefully before using it with meat?  I gather there are a number of philosophical responses to this question, such as honoring your forbears, etc.  In my mind, they clash with the spirit of what Moses said--that  the logic of laws should be clear to us.

Comment: In addition to the answer below: Louis Jacobs’ ‘A Tree of Life’. For another side of the spectrum ‘Likkute Halachos’ from R. Nosson, student of R. Nachman of Breslov. Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically it is possible to switch from dairy to meaty utensils every time and perform *hagala* in between. We don't do it for practical reasons, to avoid mistakes, based on a gemara in Chulin 8b (see [here](https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/kashering-from-meat-to-milk-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter) for details).

I don't know if you meant to ask specifically for this or more generally about the fundamental rationale of *mitzvot*, you might enjoy the following books

- [Sefer HaChinuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch) which explains all mitzvot and their rationale ([Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh?lang=bi), [artscroll translation](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422611890.html), [summarized book](https://www.feldheim.com/concise-sefer-hachinuch.html))
- R David Silverstein's [Jewish Law as a Journey](https://www.korenpub.com/maggid_en_usd/catalog/product/view/id/1195/s/jewish-law-as-journey/category/2/) which, in easy language, explains the philosophical underpinning behind many *mitzvot*
- [The mitzvot: The Commandments and Their Rationale](http://www.urimpublications.com/the-mitzvot-the-commandments-and-their-rationale.html)

Comment: He's not talking about hagala. He's saying use non porous utensils so you don't even need hagala to switch back and forth since there's nothing absorbed. You can't make a mistake if it's always pareve.

Comment: Do these things exist for cooking utensils? Glass?

Comment: Undoubtedly, they exist scientifically. To what extent they are commonly available and to what extent rabbis are willing to accept the relevant scientific proof is another question. Stainless steel absorbs less than you can imagine but rabbis for the most part still pretend it absorbs substantial amounts.